# Is the dban quick method for HDD equal to a full wipe?

Tags: hard-drive, wipe, dban

I wiped my HDD with DBAN and the quick method. Craig Steven Wrigt says it‘s secure to erase an HDD one time. I think so too, but is the DBAN quick wipe a full one time wipe?

Comment: No one here can tell you what you consider to be safe...

Comment: If you're that paranoid, use a hammer (not on your head) or see a psychologist.

Comment: (Almost) duplicate: [Disk Erasing Security - Odd Number of
Writes](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35768/) on security.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define "safe".  Tinfoil-hat safe? no.  State police safe? absolutely.  Federal-safe? mostly.  NSA-safe? probably not.

Honestly, if you're seriously worried... nothin' some thermite won't fix.

Comment: If it is not an SSD be sure to take the magnets out prior to the thermite. Never waste good magnets.

Comment: HI-FIVE!  Magnets are awesome.

Comment: Good point on the magnets. +1

Comment: DBAN in fact includes a MoD level wipe option as well, why someone would not jut run this instead if they are worried, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on any reasonably new (> 100 gig drive) this is safe - even NSA safe.

NSA can't magically rewrite the laws of physics, and the recovery rate using microscopy (ie looking at the surface of the disk) on a disk overwritten is only slightly better then chance - on a PER BIT basis - this means that once you start recovering more then a couple of bytes (not kilobytes, bytes) - let alone the length of a private key even the NSA can't recover it.

The larger the disk capacity, the smaller the chance of even recovering bits of information.

Read the conclusion of [this](https://www.vidarholen.net/~vidar/overwriting_hard_drive_data.pdf) paper (or the whole paper to understand the issue)